# Why can't I compare null field to a primitive

Tags: java

Could you please tell me why I get a NullPointerException here?

```
public class N {
    private Integer n = null;
    public static void main(String... wargh) {
        N obj = new N();
        System.out.println(obj.n == 1);
    }
}
```

The `obj.n` is (obviously!) `null` here, so `obj.n == 1` must return `false` - just the same way as `null == 1` returns `false`. But it does not. Instead, it throws an exception.

Comment: primitives can not possibly have a 'null' value, this is only possible for objects. Just so you know: Integer is not a primitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `obj.n == 1` is interpreted as primitive integer comparison, so `obj.n` will be auto-unboxed calling `out.n.intValue()`, which leads to the exception.

Formally, [JLS 15.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) makes it clear that compiler knows your code is a numeric comparison, and then [JLS 15.21.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) applies which states:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I needed to understand the problem.

Answer (score 5):

`null` cannot be compared to a primitive, since a primitive can never be equal to `null`.

`null == 1` doesn't return `false` - it doesn't pass compilation.

Comparing an `Integer` to an `int` requires unboxing of the `Integer` into an `int`. `obj.n == 1` throws `NullPointException` when `obj.n == null`, since unboxing `obj.n` is equivalent to executing `obj.n.intValue()`.